# How to add whitespaces between two words in a string so that total string length has specific value

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am starting out with strings (creditcard numbers and validity status) such as:

```
'378282246310005 Invalid',
'30569309025904 Invalid',
'6011111111111117 valid'
```

and I would like to obtain final strings, where the total length is 40:

```
'378282246310005                  Invalid',
'30569309025904                   Invalid',
'6011111111111117                   valid'
```

Besides the Python string methods 'rjust', 'ljust' and 'center', are there any built-in string method to accomplish such a task, or would I need to write some function for it for example?

So far, I have tried:

```
string = '378282246310005 {} Invalid'
while len(string) < 40:
    string = string.format(' ')
```

Not sure how to progress from here.

Comment: You could use `replace`: `s.replace(' ', ' ' * (40-len(s)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a manual solution using `str.split` and `str.join`:

```
L = ['378282246310005 Invalid',
     '30569309025904 Invalid',
     '6011111111111117 valid']

def formatter(x):
    x_split = x.split()
    n = sum(map(len, x_split))
    return (' '*(40-n)).join(x_split)

print(*map(formatter, L), sep='\n')

378282246310005                  Invalid
30569309025904                   Invalid
6011111111111117                   valid
```

This works even if your input string contains multiple whitespace.

Comment: Worked. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Python 3's string formatting:

```
>>> a = '378282246310005 Invalid'
>>> L = a.split()
>>> middle = 40 - len(L[0])
>>> print(L[0] + f'{L[1]: >{middle}}')
378282246310005                  Invalid
```

Dealing with a list:

```
>>> for item in L:
...     item_split = item.split()
...     middle = 40 - len(item_split[0])
...     print(item_split[0] + f'{item_split[1]: >{middle}}')
... 
378282246310005                  Invalid
30569309025904                   Invalid
6011111111111117                   valid
```

Answer (score 1):

The following approach will also be very helpful for you.

```
>>> p = 353535353535
>>>
>>> credit_card_no = 378282246310005
>>> status = "Invalid"
>>>
>>> s = str(credit_card_no)
>>> l = len(s)
>>>
>>> format_string = "{:<" + str(40 - len(status)) + "}" + status
>>>
>>> answer = format_string.format(s)
>>> answer
'378282246310005                  Invalid'
>>>
>>> len(answer)
40
>>>
```

Finally, based on the above approach, we can write a reusable function like below.

```
def get_formatted_string(credit_card_no, status, width=40):
    s = str(credit_card_no)
    l = len(s)

    format_string = "{:<" + str(width - len(status)) + "}" + status
    answer = format_string.format(s)

    return answer

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inp1 = (378282246310005, 'Invalid')
    inp2 = (30569309025904, 'Invalid')
    inp3 = (6011111111111117, 'valid')

    print(get_formatted_string(*inp1))
    print(get_formatted_string(*inp2))
    print(get_formatted_string(*inp3))


# E:\Users\Rishikesh\Projects\Python3\try>python Stk_format_str.py
# 378282246310005                  Invalid
# 30569309025904                   Invalid
# 6011111111111117                   valid
```

References »

- https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/format

Comment: Finally `@Gustav`, we can have a reusable function which we can call with valid arguments to obtain the expected formatted result. I've updated my answer, please check.